# Using Index of letters in string for numeric calculation

Tags: python-3.x, indexing

`When running the following code, I'm expecting it to return a string with every even letter (based on index) being upper case and every odd number being lower case.

I'm not sure why this is happening and am hoping I can get some guidance as to what is going wrong.

Thanks for your time,
-Paul

I've tried many different iterations of essentially the idea but to no avail. I'm guessing the problem is arising from my use of indexing.

```
def myfunc(string='Null'):
list1 = [letter.upper() if string.index(letter) % 2 == 0 else letter.lower() for letter in string]
str1 = ''.join(list1)
return str1

myfunc('hello')
myfunc('anthropomorphism')
```

It seems to mostly work but it doesn't work in some cases. It seems to treat say index[3] in the word hello as not having a remainder. It will return HeLLO instead of HeLlO.

Comment: An easier way is to iterate with enumerate. For example:
`for i, letter in enumerate(string): if i % 2: ...`

Comment: A pythonic way would be to have your function simply return `''.join((c.upper() if i%2 else c.lower() for i, c in enumerate(string)))`

Comment: To explain why your code doesn't work, its because of `.index()`


From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)
`s.index(x): index of the first occurrence of x in s...`

Comment: @jean yes, go on, post it as an answer

Comment: @Pynchia, such a simple answer. Don't think it would be necessary, people can just  read the comments :)

Comment: @jean you are too modest. Answers are always valuable, even if simple, both to readers and to you. My simplest answer is still yielding me SO points on a regular basis..

Comment: Another way would be to use `itertools.cycle` and avoid the `%` operator: `''.join((c.upper() if i else c.lower() for i, c in zip(it.cycle((0,1)), s)))`

Comment: on that note, the quickest way to check for an odd number is to test its least significant bit `''.join((c.upper() if i&1 else c.lower() for i, c in enumerate(s)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
def myFunc(string = 'Null'):
    newString = ''

    for i in range(len(string)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            newString += string[i].upper()

        else:
            newString += string[i].lower()

    return newString
```

Comment: Indexing and slicing should be avoided if possible, i.e. when simple iteration suffices. The reasons are many. Please spend some time investigating the iteration protocol, iterables, iterators, generators, etc as well as mutable and immutable types

Comment: @ARD This seems to return the same answer HeLLO instead of HeLlO